# Why odds ratio in logistic regression

Tags: logistic, odds-ratio, odds

I'm a bit confused about odds ratio in logistic regression (LR). In a logistic regression textbook ([pdf](http://web.pdx.edu/~newsomj/da2/ho_logistic.pdf)), it says that the odds ratio (OR) is $OR = \exp(\beta_0 + \beta_1X)$. But, I don't understand how the $\exp(\beta)$ is linked with the odds ratio.

**This is my intuition about LR.** The equation of the LR is:
\begin{align}
\ln\bigg(\frac{p}{1-p}\bigg) &= \beta_0 + \beta_1X  \\[5pt]
&\quad\text{or}  \\[5pt]
\frac{p}{1-p} &= \exp(\beta_0 + \beta_1X)
\end{align}
Suppose that $p$ is the probability of winning a lottery, $\frac{p}{1-p}$ is then the odds of winning the lottery. Therefore, ${\rm Odds}_{{\rm win}} =  \exp(\beta_0 + \beta_1X)$. So can anyone explain how it is then linked to the OR?

Comment: What "logistic regression textbook" says this? Can you quote the passage?

Comment: Hi, I was looking at a few places, for example, http://web.pdx.edu/~newsomj/da2/ho_logistic.pdf. It says "The odds ratio is equal to exp(B),"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are right.  If the book said that, it is wrong.  I do wonder if it is a typo or a poorly phrased passage that lends itself to misunderstanding, though.  As you show, $\exp(\beta_0 + \beta_1X)$ is the *odds* of 'success' predicted by the model.  The odds ratio associated with a $1$-unit change in $X$ is $\exp(\beta)$.  You can also think of is as the factor by which you would multiply the odds  of 'success' associated with $x_i$ to get the odds associated with $(x_i + 1)$ (these are the same, phrased differently).

Since $p$ is the probability of success, $p/(1-p)$ is the odds of success by definition.  Imagine $X=0$, then the right hand side simplifies to $\exp(\beta_0)$, but the left hand side is unchanged.  Thus we can see that $\exp(\beta_0)$ is the odds of success when $X=0$. Now imagine we move to where $X=1$, then we can rewrite the RHS as $\exp(\beta_0)\times\exp(\beta_1)$ using the rules for exponentiation.  Thus we can see that $\exp(\beta_1)$ is the factor by which you would multiply the odds of success to determine the odds of success associated with a $1$-unit increase in $X$.

I think the pdf you link to is sloppily written.  At one point it says, "**Odds Ratio.** The odds ratio is equal to *exp*(*B*)", but there are no subscripts, whereas above that the intercept and the coefficient on X are differentiated by subscripts.  That sets up the reader for a misunderstanding here.

Comment: Aha, I think it is my wrong interpretation. I thought $\exp(B)$ is for the whole term i.e. $\beta_0 + \beta_1X$. So based on what you answer, the result of the equation is the odds and the exponential of the coefficient is the OR. Is this correct?

Comment: @user1480478, that's the gist of it: $\exp(\beta)$ is the odds ratio when holding all else constant.

Comment: Thank you so much I totally got it now from what you edited. Say odds of success given X=0 is $\exp(\beta)$ and the odds of success given X = 1 is $\exp(\beta) * \exp(\beta_1)$. Then the odds ratio of success to failure given the factor X is $\frac{\exp(\beta) * \exp(\beta_1)}{\exp(\beta)}$ which is equal $ \exp(\beta_1)$. Now that is my linkage from odds to odds ratio!

Comment: You're welcome, @user1480478.